# Is it possible to save flash Videos from a website using Midori browser?

Tags: video, flash, browser, midori

I have started using Midori recently. Is there a way to save/download flash videos

from websites using Midori ? I am not asking about any specific website.

Workaround: Install both youtube-dl and ClipGrab.

Answer (score 0):

You can save videos with youtube-dl. It's a command line downloader. You can view the link below it describes the ways to install and use it. It supports many many websites and very lightweight.[Click here to see the tutorial](http://www.tecmint.com/install-youtube-dl-command-line-video-download-tool/)

Comment: youtube-dl's compatibility is quite limited. It supports only a few other sites other that Youtube. I have found an app called clipgrab and it seems to work with almost any site but the  download halts midway if I try to browse the web.

Comment: @linuxyogi youtube-dl also supports almost any site. You can check this [link](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html)

Comment: Okay, I will keep both installed. If one doesn't work I will try the other. Thanks.